# Motor compatibility with pypy

Tags: pypy, tornado-motor

Does anyone know if the Motor library is compatible with pypy?

I'm running a tornado with motor and want to understand the best way to start optimising.. The choices seem between cython and pypy. It looks like the latter is the way to go however motor isn't listed as a compatible library on their website...

Answer (score 1):

I last tried Motor with PyPy a couple years ago and found it worked but slowly, I haven't re-tested since. I believe PyPy has advanced dramatically and Motor is probably fast on PyPy now.

Comment: Hi Jesse, yes I found your blog: https://emptysqua.re/blog/this-blog-is-pypy-powered/ and was wondering if there was an update since then. Thanks for the info when I'm ready I'll try and see how it goes, hopefully you're right and it has been improved drastically...